# Even with 'CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("*", )' in my Django app, I'm getting "Blocked 'frame-ancestors''' logs. What might be the issue?

Tags: django, content-security-policy

I have set **CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("*", )** in my Django application. But still, I am seeing Blocked 'frame-ancestors' in logs. Am I missing something here?